# Eigen c++ sparse matrix multiplication differs strongly for Matlab output

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I use Eigen-c++ for finite element applications of linear elasticity. I have developed a prototype code in MATLAB and tested it. Now I am trying to translate it into c++ with Eigen-c++.

I use sparse matrix multiplications, and unfortunately I have some problems; probably with precision. I use `double` numbers in my calculations and I observed a big difference between the final matrix of MATLAB and that of Eigen-c++.

Namely, a value of `1.6397029e+13` in MATLAB is `1.63974e+13` with eigen-c++. This is a difference of several millions, and generates erroneous solutions of the matrices.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You may need to read a bit about floating point accuracy. The errors you get for floating point accuracy are generally in the same decimal place (without the exponential). And actually, if you multiply very big values by small values you will enhance those errors way bigger. An error in the 5th decimal is quite OK. Also `format long g` in MATLAB. MATLAB does not display the whole number in screen unless you type that

Comment: Can you give us a minimum working example? Some short toy code that has the same problem?

Comment: Also, is it just 1 value that's off, or multiple values in the same manner? And do you know which outcome is correct, that of MATLAB or Eigen?

Comment: Note that, like andy said, the *relative* difference is only 2/100 of a ‰. In my book, that is "equal" for most applications. Give [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) a thorough read.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem in my application was not finally the floating point accuracy but some matrix values where completely off. This problem was because i shifted to the new Eigen version (3.3) going back to 3.2 the problem solved. I should post this as a bug in Eigen's page. Thank you for the useful information you shared guys!!